# Filtering haplotypes which contains AAGAGACAAG in the middle

Tags: r, dplyr

For my project, I need to find out which haplotyp (40 SNPs) is mostly causing the phenotyp.
For this I want to find out which haplotypes are associated with a very high or a very negative diplotypeffect. Because there are 294 different haplotypes, I need to select a smaller window (like 10 SNPs).

Now i want r to show me all rows where the 10 SNPs are contained in the 40 SNPs with the command:

```
filter(TailWinOAR11, mHap %in% "AAGAGACAAG")
```

But I get just this result:

> # A tibble: 0 x 7
> # ... with 7 variables: Nr `<dbl>, TierLID <chr>, mHap <chr>`,
> #   `pHap <chr>, Hapm <dbl>, Happ <dbl>, DipE <dbl>`

and no exact rows. Can anyone tell me where is the problem?

Comment: Check out `SNPassoc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`%in%` tests vector membership](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/match.html). What you want do do is *string matching*. Use `grepl` for that:

```
filter(TailWinOAR11, grepl("AAGAGACAAG", mHap, fixed = TRUE))
```

Comment: Thank you very much it is working perfectly, can i ask you a second question by the wayl. 
If i want to match that string against two columns not just mHap but pHap as well do i have to enter ``filter(TailWinOAR11, grepl("AAGAGACAAG", mHap, pHap))``